# Waffle chart in R: Legend text merely consists of "A", "B", "C"; how to change?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, waffle-chart

I have this dataframe `DF`:

```
|total | n  |
|------|----|
| 0    | 19 |
| 1    | 16 |
| 2    | 23 |
| 3    | 31 |
| 4    | 20 |
| 5    | 95 |
```

... or, to make it reproducible:

```
> dput(DF)
structure(list(total = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), n = c(19L, 16L, 23L, 
31L, 20L, 95L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now if I make a waffle chart out of it:

```
library(waffle)
waffle(DF$n, rows=6, size=0.6, 
       colors=c("#EAECEC", "#DFE0E2", "#B3B6BC", "#888D96", "#4E5656", 
                "#0A0B0B"), 
       #title="Legal Databases", 
       xlab="1 square == 1 country")
```

... I get a legend text consisting of "A", "B", "C" and so on:

[image: Waffle chart with an ABC legend text]

How can I change that legend text? I want it to read "Score: 0", "Score: 1" etc. until "Score: 5" instead of "A", "B", "C" etc.

I tried using the `names()`-solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59146919/14308375), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar solution as akrun! In the documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/waffle/waffle.pdf there is the argument `parts` = named vector of values to use for the chart:

```
library(waffle)
parts=c(DF$n)
names(parts) = paste0("Score: ", DF$total)
waffle(parts, rows=6, size=0.6, 
       colors=c("#EAECEC", "#DFE0E2", "#B3B6BC", "#888D96", "#4E5656", 
                "#0A0B0B"), 
       #title="Legal Databases", 
       xlab="1 square == 1 country")
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't notice that there is a 'total' column in the data. Nice +1

Answer (score 3):

According to [`waffle`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/waffle/versions/0.7.0/topics/waffle)

> If the vector is not named or only partially named, capital letters will be used instead.

Therefore, we could create a named vector and pass

```
library(waffle)
v1 <- setNames(DF$n, paste0("Score: ", seq_along(DF$n)-1))
waffle(v1, rows=6, size=0.6, 
       colors=c("#EAECEC", "#DFE0E2", "#B3B6BC", "#888D96", "#4E5656", 
                 "#0A0B0B"), 
        #title="Legal Databases", 
        xlab="1 square == 1 country")
```

-output

[image]